# How saves an ID and no the Data from jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, jquery-ui

I have this code:

buscarcliente.php

```
<?php
include("../../conexion.php");

$nombre=$_GET["term"]; 
$sql_cliente="SELECT cod, nombre FROM rc_clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%$nombre%'";
$buscar = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_cliente);

$json=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)) {
  array_push($json, $row['nombre']);
}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

renta_form.php JQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#cliente" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'modulos/inspeccion/buscarcliente.php'
  });
});
```

renta_form.php HTML:

```
 <tr>       
   <td><b>Cliente:</b><br><input id="cliente" name="cliente" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
```

This code shows me the values from each `id` to autocomplete an `input`, but it is saving the `name` and not the `id`, what can I do to show the value to help the user but save `id` in database?

Have a good day!

UPDATED CODE:

Now is showing me the list of the names that I am calling, but when I click the name that I want, is replace automatically by the `cod` of the `id` cliente_cod

HTML:

```
<tr>        
        <td><b>Cliente:</b><br><input id="cliente" name="cliente" type="text"></td>
        <input id="cliente_cod" name="cliente_cod" type="hidden">
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#cliente" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'modulos/renta/buscarcliente.php',
        select: function(event, ui)
        {       
            $("#cliente").val(ui.item.label);           
            $("#cliente_cod").val(ui.item.value);
        }     
    });
  });
```

PHP

```
<?php
include("../../conexion.php");

$nombre = $_GET["term"]; 
        $sql_cliente="SELECT cod, nombre FROM rc_clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%$nombre%'";
        $buscar = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_cliente);

        $json=array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)) {
                array_push($json, array('value' => $row['cod'], 'label' => $row['nombre']));
            }

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some sample data that is returned from your PHP script. IT may also be helpful to see your JavaScript code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data was something like:

```
cod     nombre
1       Homer Simpson
2       Marge Simpson
3       Bart Simpson
4       Lisa Simpson
5       Maggie Simpson
```

When you run the SQL Query, such as:

```
SELECT cod, nombre FROM rc_clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%b%'
```

You would get a result set like:

```
3       Bart Simpson
```

When we pass this back via JSON, we want a `value` and a `label`. To accomplish this, we want to do the following in the PHP. You will want to adjust your PHP as it is very **vulnerable from SQL Injection** as it is.

**PHP Snippet**

```
$json=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)) {
  array_push($json, array('value' => $row['cod'], 'label' => $row['nombre']));
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

The resulting JSON data should be:

```
[
  {
    "value": 3,
    "label": "Bart Simpson"
  }
]
```

Now we can handle how this is we are used to in the `select` callback:

**HTML Snippet**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Empleado:</b>
      <br>
      <input id="empleado" type="text">
      <input id="empleado_cod" type="hidden">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#empleado").autocomplete({
    source: 'modulos/inspeccion/buscarcliente.php',
    focus: function(event, ui){
      $("#empleado").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
      $("#empleado").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#empleado_cod").val(ui.item.value);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

See More:

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data
- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote
- http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Thank you so much!! but i have a little problem, when I look for a name is all good, the list of name appears but when I select the name the input (#empleado) (label) change by cod (value) automatically. What do you think is happening here?

Comment: @IvanJ. this suggests that you are not delegating the `value` to be stored someplace. Please edit your post and included you updated example code.

Comment: I forgot one element: `return false;`. Updating answer.